# Creating timer in HTML by using setInterval and clearInterval in JS file to limit time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to limit how much time the player has to make their guesses using the **setInterval** and **clearInterval** methods but I am not sure on how to implement this feature. How could I achieve that?

I need to think carefully about when/where to start the timer, and when to clear it. I might also consider adding a display on the HTML page to show the user how much time they have left so can someone explain to me how to go about these steps?

**PLEASE HELP**

JS File:

```
const cluePauseTime = 333; //how long to pause in between clues
const nextClueWaitTime = 1000; //how long to wait before starting playback of the clue sequence

//Global variables
var clueHoldTime = 200; //how long to hold each clue's light/sound
// var pattern = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5];
var pattern = [];
var clueLength = 10;
///////////////////////////////
var progress = 0;
var gamePlaying = false;
var tonePlaying = false;
var volume = 0.5;
var guessCounter = 0;

function startGame() {
    progress = 0;

    pattern = []; // reset so array doesn't get longer then 10 if we restart game
    for (var i = 0; i < clueLength; i++) {
        pattern.push(getRandomInt(5));
    }
    console.log("pattern: " + pattern);

    gamePlaying = true;

    document.getElementById("startBtn").classList.add("hidden");
    document.getElementById("stopBtn").classList.remove("hidden");

    playClueSequence();
}

function stopGame() {
    gamePlaying = false;
    document.getElementById("startBtn").classList.remove("hidden");
    document.getElementById("stopBtn").classList.add("hidden");
}

function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max) + 1);
}

function lightButton(btn) {
    document.getElementById("button" + btn).classList.add("lit");
}

function clearButton(btn) {
    document.getElementById("button" + btn).classList.remove("lit");
}

function playSingleClue(btn) {
    if (gamePlaying) {
        lightButton(btn);
        playTone(btn, clueHoldTime);
        setTimeout(clearButton, clueHoldTime, btn);
    }
}

function playClueSequence() {
    guessCounter = 0;
    let delay = nextClueWaitTime; //set delay to initial wait time
    for (let i = 0; i <= progress; i++) {
        // for each clue that is revealed so far
        console.log("play single clue: " + pattern[i] + " in " + delay + "ms");
        setTimeout(playSingleClue, delay, pattern[i]); // set a timeout to play that clue
        delay += clueHoldTime;
        delay += cluePauseTime;
    }
}

function loseGame() {
    stopGame();
    alert("Game Over. You lost.");
}

function winGame() {
    stopGame();
    alert("Yayyyyy, you win!!");
}

function guess(btn) {
    console.log("user guessed: " + btn);
    if (!gamePlaying) {
        return;
    }
    if (pattern[guessCounter] == btn) {
        if (guessCounter == progress) {
            if (progress == pattern.length - 1) {
                winGame();
            } else {
                progress++;
                playClueSequence();
                    }
        } else {
          guessCounter++;
        }
        //guessCounter++;
    } else {
        loseGame();
    }
}
// Sound Synthesis Functions
const freqMap = {
    1: 261.6,
    2: 329.6,
    3: 392,
    4: 466.2,
    5: 432.8,
    6: 336.2
};

function playTone(btn, len) {
    o.frequency.value = freqMap[btn];
    g.gain.setTargetAtTime(volume, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
    tonePlaying = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        stopTone();
    }, len);
}

function startTone(btn) {
    if (!tonePlaying) {
        o.frequency.value = freqMap[btn];
        g.gain.setTargetAtTime(volume, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
        tonePlaying = true;
    }
}

function stopTone() {
    g.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
    tonePlaying = false;
}

//Page Initialization
// Init Sound Synthesizer
var context = new AudioContext();
var o = context.createOscillator();
var g = context.createGain();
g.connect(context.destination);
g.gain.setValueAtTime(0, context.currentTime);
o.connect(g);
o.start(0);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <title>Hello!</title>

        <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

        <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
        <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Memory Game</h1>

        <p>
          Welcome to the game that will test your memory!
        </p>

        <button id="startBtn" onclick="startGame()">
            Start
        </button>
        <button id="stopBtn" class="hidden" onclick="stopGame()">
            Stop
        </button>

        <div id="gameButtonArea">
            <button
                id="button1"
                onclick="guess(1)"
                onmousedown="startTone(1)"
                onmouseup="stopTone()"
            ></button>
            <button
                id="button2"
                onclick="guess(2)"
                onmousedown="startTone(2)"
                onmouseup="stopTone()"
            ></button>
            <button
                id="button3"
                onclick="guess(3)"
                onmousedown="startTone(3)"
                onmouseup="stopTone()"
            ></button>
            <button
                id="button4"
                onclick="guess(4)"
                onmousedown="startTone(4)"
                onmouseup="stopTone()"
            ></button>
            <button
                id="button5"
                onclick="guess(5)"
                onmousedown="startTone(5)"
                onmouseup="stopTone()"
            ></button>
            <button
                id="button6"
                onclick="guess(6)"
                onmousedown="startTone(6)"
                onmouseup="stopTone()"
            ></button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 2em;
    background-color: slategrey;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    color: yellow;
}

button {
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#gameButtonArea > button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 2px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#button1 {
    background: lightgreen;
}

#button1:active,
#button1.lit {
    background: green;
}

#button2 {
    background: lightblue;
}

#button2:active,
#button2.lit {
    background: blue;
}

#button3 {
    background: pink;
}

#button3:active,
#button3.lit {
    background: red;
}

#button4 {
    background: lightyellow;
}

#button4:active,
#button4.lit {
    background: yellow;
}

#button5 {
    background: lightgray;
}

#button5:active,
#button5.lit {
    background: black;
}

#button6 {
    background: white;
}

#button6:active,
#button6.lit {
    background: purple;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle with a possible solution, hope it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/arksyLxw/24/

Please note the only thing I couldn't get working with the limited time I had to work on this was a call to `loseGame` from within the `myTimer` function it is undefined due to the fact it is being call within a asynchronous function.

**Edit:** Nevermind it was a simple spelling error lol had `LoseGame` not `loseGame`
https://jsfiddle.net/ts25hyru/4/

---

```js
const cluePauseTime = 333; //how long to pause in between clues
const nextClueWaitTime = 1000; //how long to wait before starting playback of the clue sequence

//Global variables
var countDownTimer;
var timeLimit = 6;
var currentTime;

var clueHoldTime = 200; //how long to hold each clue's light/sound
// var pattern = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5];
var pattern = [];
var clueLength = 10;
///////////////////////////////
var progress = 0;
var gamePlaying = false;
var tonePlaying = false;
var volume = 0.5;
var guessCounter = 0;

function startGame() {
  progress = 0;

  pattern = []; // reset so array doesn't get longer then 10 if we restart game
  for (var i = 0; i < clueLength; i++) {
    pattern.push(getRandomInt(5));
  }
  console.log("pattern: " + pattern);

  gamePlaying = true;

  document.getElementById("startBtn").classList.add("hidden");
  document.getElementById("stopBtn").classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById("timeDiv").classList.remove("hidden");

  playClueSequence();
}

function stopGame() {
  clearInterval(countDownTimer); // remember to clear interval to prevent memory leaks

  gamePlaying = false;
  document.getElementById("startBtn").classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById("stopBtn").classList.add("hidden");
}

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max) + 1);
}

function lightButton(btn) {
  document.getElementById("button" + btn).classList.add("lit");
}

function clearButton(btn) {
  document.getElementById("button" + btn).classList.remove("lit");
}

function playSingleClue(btn) {
  if (gamePlaying) {
    lightButton(btn);
    playTone(btn, clueHoldTime);
    setTimeout(clearButton, clueHoldTime, btn);
  }
}

function playClueSequence() {
  console.log('Entered playClueSequence');

  guessCounter = 0;
  let delay = nextClueWaitTime; //set delay to initial wait time
  for (let i = 0; i <= progress; i++) {
    // for each clue that is revealed so far
    console.log("play single clue: " + pattern[i] + " in " + delay + "ms");
    setTimeout(playSingleClue, delay, pattern[i]); // set a timeout to play that clue
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (i === progress) {
        // document.getElementById("timeDiv").classList.remove("hidden"); // might be useful for styling timer
        console.log('played final clue ...');

        currentTime = timeLimit; // this should reset every round
        countDownTimer = setInterval(() => {
                    myTimer();
                }, 1000);

      }
    }, delay);

    delay += clueHoldTime;
    delay += cluePauseTime;

  }

  console.log('sequence complete');
}

function myTimer() {
  console.log('counting down');

  currentTime = (currentTime - 1); // can also do currentTime --

  if (currentTime <= 0) {
    currentTime = 0;
     document.getElementById("timeDiv").innerHTML = ('Time remaing: ' + currentTime);

    clearInterval(countDownTimer);
    loseGame();
  }

  document.getElementById("timeDiv").innerHTML = ('Time remaing: ' + currentTime);
}

function loseGame() {
  stopGame();
  alert("Game Over. You lost.");
}

function winGame() {
  stopGame();
  alert("Yayyyyy, you win!!");
}

function guess(btn) {
  console.log("user guessed: " + btn);
  if (!gamePlaying) {
    return;
  }
  if (pattern[guessCounter] == btn) {
    if (guessCounter == progress) {
      if (progress == pattern.length - 1) {
        winGame();
      } else {
        // document.getElementById("timeDiv").classList.add("hidden"); // might be useful for styling timer
        clearInterval(countDownTimer); // we guess correctly so stop timer

        progress++;
        playClueSequence();
      }
    } else {
      guessCounter++;
    }
    //guessCounter++;
  } else {
    loseGame();
  }
}
// Sound Synthesis Functions
const freqMap = {
  1: 261.6,
  2: 329.6,
  3: 392,
  4: 466.2,
  5: 432.8,
  6: 336.2
};

function playTone(btn, len) {
  o.frequency.value = freqMap[btn];
  g.gain.setTargetAtTime(volume, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
  tonePlaying = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    stopTone();
  }, len);
}

function startTone(btn) {
  if (!tonePlaying) {
    o.frequency.value = freqMap[btn];
    g.gain.setTargetAtTime(volume, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
    tonePlaying = true;
  }
}

function stopTone() {
  g.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
  tonePlaying = false;
}

//Page Initialization
// Init Sound Synthesizer
var context = new AudioContext();
var o = context.createOscillator();
var g = context.createGain();
g.connect(context.destination);
g.gain.setValueAtTime(0, context.currentTime);
o.connect(g);
o.start(0);
```

```css
body {
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 2em;
    background-color: slategrey;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    color: yellow;
}

button {
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#gameButtonArea > button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 2px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#button1 {
    background: lightgreen;
}

#button1:active,
#button1.lit {
    background: green;
}

#button2 {
    background: lightblue;
}

#button2:active,
#button2.lit {
    background: blue;
}

#button3 {
    background: pink;
}

#button3:active,
#button3.lit {
    background: red;
}

#button4 {
    background: lightyellow;
}

#button4:active,
#button4.lit {
    background: yellow;
}

#button5 {
    background: lightgray;
}

#button5:active,
#button5.lit {
    background: black;
}

#button6 {
    background: white;
}

#button6:active,
#button6.lit {
    background: purple;
}

#timeDiv {
  position: relative;  
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <title>Hello!</title>

        <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

        <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
        <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Memory Game</h1>
        
        <div id="timeDiv" class="hidden">Time remaing: 0</div>
        
        <p>
          Welcome to the game that will test your memory!
        </p>

        <button id="startBtn" onclick="startGame()">
            Start
        </button>
        <button id="stopBtn" class="hidden" onclick="stopGame()">
            Stop
        </button>

        <div id="gameButtonArea">
            <button
                id="button1"
                onclick="guess(1)"
                onmousedown="startTone(1)"
                onmouseup="stopTone()"
            ></button>
            <button
                id="button2"
                onclick="guess(2)"
                onmousedown="startTone(2)"
                onmouseup="stopTone()"
            ></button>
            <button
                id="button3"
                onclick="guess(3)"
                onmousedown="startTone(3)"
                onmouseup="stopTone()"
            ></button>
            <button
                id="button4"
                onclick="guess(4)"
                onmousedown="startTone(4)"
                onmouseup="stopTone()"
            ></button>
            <button
                id="button5"
                onclick="guess(5)"
                onmousedown="startTone(5)"
                onmouseup="stopTone()"
            ></button>
            <button
                id="button6"
                onclick="guess(6)"
                onmousedown="startTone(6)"
                onmouseup="stopTone()"
            ></button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the answer. Link only answers are strongly discouraged.